# How to check Multiple Points are exists in a Multiple Polygons

Tags: mysql, gis

Hello everyone I have a case where I need to find any point(lat, long) located inside a specific zone (geometry of type polygon) I have two tables `zones`, and `points`

**zones** table

```
id,
name,
area (data type of geometry)
```

**points** table

```
id,
address,
lat,
long
```

lat and long (data type of double)

I tried this query and it works fine but I cannot manage how to add multiple points to the query, in other words how can I add the whole **lat** and **long** in table **points**

```
SET @multi_polygon = ST_GeomFromText('MultiPolygon(((-72.2796106 42.9282426, -72.2819495 42.9280383, -72.2814775 42.9264358, -72.2792459 42.9267578, -72.2796106 42.9282426),(1 1,1 2,2 2,2 1,1 1)))');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    zones
WHERE
    ST_WITHIN(
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.2798356 42.9278498)'),
        @multi_polygon
    );
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ST_WITHIN(..)`

Comment: @Akina not right

Comment: If so then you did something incorrectly. Have you converted lat/lon to correct POINT?

Comment: @Akina how can i join both tables there is no relation between them at all -_-

Comment: o_O Joining tables and relation between the tables are not related. At all. Joining sets the matching condition whereas relation sets the checking rule.

Comment: Okay, can you join these tables and explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

> can you join these tables and explain it to me – Judge Jules

```sql
SELECT *
FROM zones
JOIN points ON ST_WITHIN( ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', points.lat, ' ', points.lon, ')'), 
                          zones.area );
```

CONCAT converts separate coordinates to correct WKT. ST_GeomFromText converts it to POINT. Then ST_WITHIN checks does the point is posessed within the area.

As a result you obtain all separate pairs point-area where the point is posessed within the area.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination and support, I tried the query but I got a syntax error
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 15" I did not use LIMIT in my query

Comment: @JudgeJules This may be "a service" provided by your client software. Check using CLI.

Comment: did you mean it's an MYSQL configuration?